# AMP tags are valid(using validater.js and chrome plugin) but failing when testing in google AMP test

Tags: amp-html, amp-analytics, amp-ad

I have created AMP enabled blog detail page, it showing valid when checked using development=1. Ie, https://datafloq.com/read/amp/7-industries-where-augmented-reality-making-mark/4567#development=1 and when checked using chrome extension.[image: When development=1]

[image: Using chrome extension]

Seems all the AMP tags are valid. But when I cheked it using google AMP test it showing lot of errors. https://search.google.com/test/amp?id=zbtk04M2v-poJamuIIV7hQ.

FYI:
It uses amp-ad for ads, amp-analytics for google analytics, amp-iframe for showing disqus comment.

Do I need to add anything else to make the google amp validation success?

Comment: AMPHTML mentions in [AMPHTML Specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec) that "it does not allow author written JavaScript beyond what is provided through the custom elements to reach its performance goals.""

Comment: @noogui I am actually using amp-ad(3 times), amp-analytics(1 time), amp-iframe(1 time for disqus). But all of them based on the AMP instructions. Is there any limit for this kind of tags? Thanks

Comment: Does this cloudflare affect AMP page validation?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I faced was due to the prerender.io using in the production site. Disabled prerender of AMP pages and it started working on the google AMP test.

Note: For Googlebot, the HTML was rendering from the prerender while for the browser the server was returning HTML. That's why it is getting validated in the browser but Google AMP test not.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/amphtml-discuss/9OIT3a-uMzY